# How do you get a AjaxFileUpload control to see what is in a textbox on a form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I know that AjaxFileUpload is asynchronous, but is there a work around to get the control to see the value of a text box on the same form?

I would like to have the text box for the user to type in the description of the uploaded file, but in the OnUploadComplete event handler, the control basically sees nothing.  I hope there is a workaround.

Comment: I think you can only `get` the filename in code from the upload control; there's no setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this:

Set AutoPostBack for the DropDownList to true and handle the SelectedIndexChanged event to set the selected value in Session. Then consume the Session value in OnUploadComplete event.